Images are not showing in shared hosting Laravel 10
I have deployed small project with image uploading feature to the shared hosting. The images are not showing in the view file. Images are saving correctly to the following folder.
/storage/app/public/images/posts/featured-images

there is no way to run "php artisan storage:link" command , because unavailability of SSH.
I did try this in web.php
Route::get('/foo', function () {
Artisan::call('storage:link');
});

This created a link to public folder , but still not showing the images.
When I open broken image link it shows  image path to the
www.mywebsite.com/storage/images/posts/featured-images/kpa5ffcQZngbzriIdvnO0GyjFn2RoXBXDHdAlyJ7.jpg

There are lots of post regarding this , I have tried most.
